# laravel dynamic scope not working

Tags: php, laravel, scope

I try to get my categories base on their status and i have `scope` below in my category model:

```
public function scopeOfStatus($query, $status)
{
     return $query->where('status_id', $status);
}
```

And my controller is like:

```
public function finder() {
    $findercategories = Category::OfStatus('Active')->get();
    return response()->json($findercategories);
}
```

My route is like:

```
Route::get('/finder','frontend\SearchController@finder');
```

But i get blank page as result. Any idea?

## update

if i use `$findercategories = Category::ofStatus(1)->get();` i get the result that i want but it's static not dynamic :\

Comment: Check `storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: change `Category::OfStatus` to `Category::ofStatus`

Comment: @SapneshNaik still blank.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin nothing adds in to it.

Comment: @mafortis you status_id is supposed to contain 'Active'?

Comment: what do means by `static not dynamic` ?

Comment: @SapneshNaik no it gets id of status from `statuses` table

Comment: @user2486 using `1` or `2` or any other id's is static using `active` is dynamic.

Comment: @Bugfixer any sample?

Comment: @mafortis Do you mean there is a mapping like `active => 1, 'inactive' => 2` that you'd like to use when applying query scope?

Comment: @linktoahref yes my statuses table is like that active => ID 1 and so on. so i only get that id in my categories table. now i want return if id that saved in my category table equals with title Active then show it.

Comment: @Bugfixer yes it does, and no your `ScopeActive` doesn't work also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the Id's from the `statuses` table with respect to the searched value and use the Id's to get the Category

```
public function scopeOfStatus($query, $status)
{
    $statuses = Status::where('title', $status)->pluck('id'); // Or relevant column name
    return $query->whereIn('status_id', $statuses);
}
```

and in your Controller you could do so

```
public function finder() {
    $findercategories = Category::ofStatus('Active')->get();
    return response()->json($findercategories);
}
```